# file changed as we read it, Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Tags: 14.04

I'm trying to make a back up of my system according to [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=35087).

```
sudo su
cd /
tar cvpzf backup.tgz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/backup.tgz --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys --exclude=/media /
```

But I keep getting this error when cvpzf tries to back up `initramfs`

```
...
/run/initramfs/
file changed as we read it
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would run into the same error when trying to back up my entire `$HOME`.

It comes as no surprise that some files in my `$HOME` (or, in your case, on the entire system) would undergo changes at some point during the lengthy processing of archiving everything... The output message is helpful and explanatory.

In the end, I only backed up the content of my `~/Documents`! The rest either lives online or I consider I should not depend on.

Alternatively, you may not care about the inconsistencies due to file differences between start and end (of the archiving process)...  Not sure whether the rest of the archiving continues smoothly after hitting a changed file.  At some point, I believe you have to try and break things.  Have you tried restoring that backup, in spite of the error message?  How did it go?  I'm sure you've learnt a lot!